# RM job was stuck when running with oozie

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, oozie, hadoop2

I'm running a mapreduce wordcount job task on oozie. 2 jobs were submitted to the yarn, and then the monitoring tasks running upto 99% were stuck. Wordcount job has been 0%.

When I kill off the monitor job, wordcount job runs smoothly.

I use a cluster of 3 virtual machines, configuration is as follows:

```
 Profile per VM: cores=2 memory=2048MB reserved=0GB usableMem=0GB disks=1
 Num Container=3
 Container Ram=640MB
 Used Ram=1GB
 Unused Ram=0GB
 yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=640
 yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb=1920
 yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=1920
 mapreduce.map.memory.mb=640
 mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx512m
 mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=1280
 mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx1024m
 yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb=640
 yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts=-Xmx512m
 mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb=256
```

Is there any way to solve this, to make two jobs run smoothly and finish at the same time ?

Comment: my oozie version is 4.3.0,hadoop version is 2.7.2.

Comment: Check the capacity scheduler properties: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Setting_up_ResourceManager_to_use_CapacityScheduler You might need to increase it for queue or am for allowing them to launch more AM jobs (taking more resource).

Comment: it's works!i have solved it yet,think you!

Comment: It would be nice to add your solution as answer for the future readers. Thank You.